# Objects behave as individual objects after joining

Tags: python, scripting, objects

**Situation**

I have about 10 objects in the scene that I appended from another Blender file. I unlinked the group and now all the objects are independent as shown in figure 1[image]. I selected all the objects and joined them using bpy.ops.object.join() and this shows up in the outliner as a single object as shown in figure 2[image].

**Issue**

When I loop in bpy.data.objects, I still get the list of all individual objects(printed all the objects names in console), while I have only one joined object (as checked in GUI - figure 2)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Could you add the script you are using to your question ? (I mean the exact sequence, as I have followed the step you indicate in the question and my result is one object in bpy.data.objects)

Comment: Before calling `bpy.ops.object.join()`, try calling `bpy.ops.object.select_all( action = 'SELECT' )`

Comment: Could be an object.users issue. If an object has more than one user it will not be removed from the bpy.data.objects collection, only unlinked from the scene after using the join op. There is a scene.objects collection for all the objects linked to a scene.

Comment: Couldn't really find the reason why this was happening. But found a work around for this. Instead of grouping the objects and appending the group and then unlinking the group, I simply appended all the objects individually into the new blender file. Now I join the objects using bpy.ops.object.join() and tada, it works. Now the object count is 1.